# Database Error Occurred

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI and my database is on dream host. And when i connect database. it gives error like this

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided
>   settings.
>
> Filename:
>   /home/demo_smartmobe/demos.smartmobe.com/nayacinema/webpart/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 98

my ci code for database connection is

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'hostname';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = '​******';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

username and password is correct.
and i had tried by simple php code and it works. Php Code  is here.

```
$hostname = "mysql.demos.smartmobe.com";   // eg. mysql.yourdomain.com (unique)
$username = "nayacinema";   // the username specified when setting-up the database
$password = "****";   // the password specified when setting-up the database
$database = "nayacinema";   // the database name chosen when setting-up the database (unique)



$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo 'done';
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM TblUsers");
print_r($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

what may be the problem? I had add MX folder in Ci folder for make it HMVC. And error is shown in /third_party/MX/Loader.php. IN localhost in works but in live there is error .please help me. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You stated your username and password are correct, but what about the hostname?

Modify your hostname setting to be your correct hostname.

E.g.

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`

or

`$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';`

You will also need to change `$db['default']['database_name']` to match the name of the database you're attempting to use.

Comment: my database is on dreamhost and i used 'mysql.demos.smartmobe.com'.Is hostname should be '127.0.0.1'? I am quite confused. database is also correct

Comment: I don't know what your database server is, surely you should.

Comment: It doesn't work. Is htaccess make problem for connect database?

Comment: No, htaccess wouldn't affect your database connectivity. When you say it doesn't work, I presume you're getting the same error as in your original post. We can't help you - you're providing the wrong values for either `hostname`, `database_name`, or the credentials.

Comment: I don't know that you're understanding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the correct database connection info from Dreamhost. You can find the ones that you have set up for that domain in your Dreamhost Web Panel, under the MySQL Databases tab, on the left side. Under that page, you can find the hostname, database, and username. If you click on the username that has access to the database, you can find out what your password is. Put those values into your `database.php` config file, like in the fields show below.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql.example.com';
$db['default']['port']     = "3306";  
$db['default']['username'] = 'mysql_username';
$db['default']['password'] = '​mysql_password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mysql_database';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are accessing the database within the same pc.
(`localhost and 127.0.0.1` are the same)

If not, the host name should be identified by DNS Name or with domain name included.

And if the database port is not the default (3306), you should include it on the config.

Like the code in your php:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql.demos.smartmobe.com';
$db['default']['username'] = 'nayacinema';
$db['default']['password'] = '​******';
$db['default']['database'] = 'nayacinema';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
//$db['default']['port'] = 3307;        //modify if the port is not the default 3306
```